# Azure DevOps breaking when using .Net 6.0

Tags: .net, azure-devops, .net-6.0

##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1201: Project Demo is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Project Demo supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

This is my Yaml file

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
# Add this Command to Include the .NET 6 SDK
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use .NET 6.0
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'

# Add a Command To List the Current .NET SDKs (Sanity Check)
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet --list-sdks'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: What .NET version does `Project Demo` use?

Comment: Its using .net 6.0